# Trying to Download Ubuntu 14.04 with ImgBurn; Received I/O Error!

Tags: preinstallation

So I'm trying to download Ubuntu with a CD-R, but I got an error message. I can't place a picture, because I need 10 reputation, but here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVQvT.jpg)

The download is at 99%, and I clicked try again, but it failed three times now. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu 14.04 iso file is too large to fit on a CD, so you have to use either a DVD or a USB flash drive that has at least 2GB to make the Ubuntu 14.04 installation media. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the USB flash drive should be 4GB or larger. Two useful tutorials at www.ubuntu.com are:

1. [How to burn a DVD on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) - This  tutorial includes a link to download the Ubuntu 14.04 installation file.
2. [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks Karel. I actually, got it to work by burning it again on the same kind of CD. For some reason it worked that time. The CD, contained 4GB of space, so it probably was the space. Thanks.

Comment: When you start using Ubuntu you will find that the default optical disk burning application, Brasero, has a **Simulation** feature that allows you to simulate the burning process without actually burning the CD or DVD. This will identify some bad/unusable disks before it starts to burn them, which will prevent you from having to burn useless disks.